# Timing out DriverManager.getConnection()?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I'm working with Java and mysql for database and I ran into a weird problem:
One of my clients have a very unstable connection and sometimes packet loss can be high. Ok that's not software's fault I know, but I went there to test and, when the program calls "DriverManager.getConnection()" and the network connection gets unstable, that line gets to lock the application (or the given thread) by several minutes. I have added some logics of course to use another datasource for caching data locally then saving to the network host when possible, but, I can't often let the program hang for longer than 10s (And this method doesn't seem to have any timeout specification).
So, I came out with a workaround like this:

```
public class CFGBanco implements Serializable {
    public String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    public String host;
    public String url = "";
    public String proto = "jdbc:mysql://";
    public String database;
    public String user;
    public String password;
}

private static java.sql.Connection Connect(HostConfig dataHost) throws java.sql.SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        dataHost.url = dataHost.proto+dataHost.host;
        if(dataHost.database != null && !dataHost.database.equals("")) dataHost.url += "/"+dataHost.database;
        java.lang.Class.forName(dataHost.driver);
            ArrayList<Object> lh = new ArrayList<>();
            lh.add(0, null);
            Thread ConThread = new Thread(()-> {
                try {
                    lh.add(0, java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(
                        dataHost.url, dataHost.user, dataHost.password));
                } catch(Exception x ) {
                    System.out.println(x.getMessage());
                }
            }, "ConnThread-"+SessId);
            ConThread.start();
            Thread TimeoutThread = new Thread(() -> {
                int c = 0;
                int delay = 100;
                try {
                    try {
                        do {
                            try {
                                if(t.isAlive())
                                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                                else
                                    break;
                            } catch(Exception x) {}
                        } while((c+=delay) < 10000);
                    } catch(Exception x){}
                } finally { 
                    try {
                        t.stop();
                    } catch(Exception x){}
                }
            }, "ConTimeout-"+SessId);
            TimeoutThread.start();
            try {
                ConThread.join();
            } catch(Exception x) {}
            if(lh.get(0) == null)
                throw new SQLException();
        return (Connection) lh.get(0);
    }
```

I call getConnection from another thread, then make a secondary "timeout" thread to watch it and then Join the calling thread to the ConThread.
I have been getting results close to expected, indeed, but it got me wondering:
Is there a better way to do this? Does the creation of 2 threads eat up much on system resources, enough to make this approach unpractical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need connection pooling. Pool in the connection and reuse it rather than recreating everytime. One such library for DB connection pooling is [DBCP by Apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)

It will take care of when connection gets dropped off and so on. You could have validation Query and it would query DB say before borrowing connection from the pool and once it validates successfully, it will fire your actual query.

Comment: Very nice indeed, ty.